# Is there an Excel formula that populates a number of cells, if a certain value is entered in another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have an excel spreadsheet with a number of headings to collect certain information. As an example:

In column A I have a heading (Heading1), and in the rest of the cells in this column through data validation there is only three possible pieces of text that can be entered here (text1, text2, text3).

If 'text1' is entered, in column B and C I would like 'Heading 2' and 'Heading 3' to populate.

If 'text2' is entered, in column B and C I would like 'Heading 3' and 'Heading 4' to populate.

If 'text3' is entered, in column B and C I would like 'Heading 5' and 'Heading 6' to populate.

Is there a formula or rule which can allow this, or is it not possible?

Comment: Look at the [CHOOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHOOSE-function-fce63190-b514-48cc-a7ff-c1cdaaec0907).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the headers in **A1** through **A6**, in **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2="text1",$B$1,IF(A2="text2",$C$1,IF(A2="text3",$E$1,"")))
```

and in **C2** enter:

```
=IF(A2="text1",$C$1,IF(A2="text2",$D$1,IF(A2="text3",$F$1,"")))
```

[image]